# Using socket.io for notifications and chat

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, long-polling

I'm very new to node.js and sokcet.io that's why I need to ask you about the plan I have to see if it makes sense or is plain stupid. I need ongoing server/client communication for two reasons: sending real-time notifications to the user when they have one, and two, for chat between users.

Here is my plan for managing notifications:

1. PHP script finds out user X has a new notification.
2. Using Elephant.io send a message to server with user X's id as the data.
3. On the server side, upon receiving the message, if user X is connected emit him a message telling they have a notification.
4. user X's brower, Upon recieving the message, uses AJAX to poll the database and receive the text for the notification.

For chat, this is my plan (messages should be save on DB):

1. When user X submits a chat message to user Y, use ajax to send the text to a PHP script and save it on DB. On success, use elephant.io to send a message to user Y telling them that they have a new chat message.
2. User Y's browser, after receiving the server message, uses AJAX to poll a php script to receive the new text.

Do you think these plans are superior to short polling using AJAX? I appreciate any comments to improve them.

Finally,I'm curious to know how reliable these technologies (node.js, socket.io, elephant.io) are. Do they work well when the server becomes busy? How do they handle exceptions and errors ,etc.

Comment: the point of  websockets is  not to use ajax anymore , at least for the part of "to poll the database"

Comment: But without websockets I have to poll every few seconds, while with them, I just to it when necessary.

Comment: Why not send the message through the sockets then you don't need an ajax reequest